# Access SQL query over time

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am currently tracking how many employees are at work every hour over a 12 hour period.  I can do this by using a table with start and end times and a table with 1 entry per hour over 12 hours from 5am to 5pm.  I am curious if there is a way to do a time interval without having to create the time table.

```
SELECT COUNT(IIF(ISNULL(Start_Name), End_Name, Start_Name)) AS Total, lookup_time
FROM tblWorkers5to17, TimeTable
WHERE lookup_time BETWEEN IIF(ISNULL(Start_Time), TimeValue(#05:00#),TimeValue([Start_Time])) AND IIF(ISNULL(End_Time), TimeValue(#17:00#), TimeValue([End_Time]))
GROUP BY lookup_time;
```

This gives me what I need, but, I was hoping for a way that I could avoid a table of times and I could change easier if I wanted a different interval.

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  But you will need an auxiliary table if you want zero values returned (which your query does not do).

Comment: @hcant, please post data to *show* us what you have and what you want and not *tell* us.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry for the lack of data.  I will update when I can, but, I think it was answered already.  Thanks for the input and direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, the time table must exist. However, there are ways which you can dynamically create that time table using recursion and common table expressions, so you don't have to manually create this table... but the answer might depend on what SQL RDBMS you use. Can you specify what kind of SQL system you're working with?

This is just a personal preference, but I would spend time making the TimeTable exist going backwards as far back as makes sense, and 20 years into the future. Then I'd index it and be done with it. You could then filter in your WHERE clause to the times which you care about, each time you run it. But some may prefer to dynamically create a new TimeTable with each run where it isn't stored in your schema.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  This is just a daily run Access database for reports.  I should have put that in the original question.  The raw data is .csv file from another system that tracks, but, doesn't have a good way to currently create reports or even my personalize the criteria I want to use.

Comment: @hcant That makes sense. I would setup a TimeTable in your Access DB then. Extend it backwards and forwards in time so that you won't have to ever recreate it, and then add a condition to your join where you're only caring about certain date ranges.